# Can you fake out Array.isArray() with a user-defined object?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious about whether there is any way to fake out `Array.isArray()` with a user-defined object.

From the book JavaScript Patterns:

```
Array.isArray([]); // true

// trying to fool the check
// with an array-like object
Array.isArray({
  length: 1,
  "0": 1,
  slice: function () {}
}); // false
```

That object clearly fails, but is there any other way to do it? This is sheer curiosity, and not because I think that you could ever screw with `.isArray()` in regular client code (though it would obviously be fantastic to know if you could!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only if you set the [internal `[[Class]]` property](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6.2) to `"Array"`, which is not possible afaik. From the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.4.3.2):

> The `isArray` function takes one argument `arg`, and returns the Boolean value `true` if the argument is an object whose class internal property is "Array"; otherwise it returns `false`.

Or you go the other way round: Create a normal array and explicitly set every array method to `undefined`.

Comment: Now you've prompted me to ask a follow-on question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672204/can-you-set-the-internal-class-property-of-an-ecmascript-object

Answer (score 11):

`Array.isArray = function () { return true; }`

And if you want to be naughty

```
Array.isArray.toString = function () { 
  return 'function () { [native code] }';
};
```