# Can you set the internal [[Class]] property of an ECMAScript object?

Tags: javascript

Can you set [the internal [[Class]] property](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.6.2) of an ECMAScript object?

Comment: Note that the internal [[Class]] property will be removed in ES6.

Comment: @Raynos Interesting. So how will `Array.isArray()` and similar functions work then?

Comment: not sure, they will use some sensible detection, maybe `Array.protototype.isPrototypeOf(someArray);`

Comment: @JoshSmith `function isArray(x) { return [].concat(x)[0] !== x; }` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trick decent javascript engines.

You can trick user land code with

```
x.toString = function () {
  return '[object Array]';
}
```

Comment: This won't work with `Object.prototype.toString.call(object)`.

Comment: @xfix One can always override `Object#toString` (though not recommended at all)

Comment: @minmaxavg But the reason one would want to override `[[class]]` is usually because they want to use it with `Object.prototype.toString.call` to get the type of the object.