# How does the Array.isArray() method check for array?

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

**Scope:** I have been learning `prototype inheritance` in java script and I tried the following code in my web browser. I found something really interesting while executing the following code.

```
let animal = {
  eats: true
};
let rabbit = {
  jumps: true
};
const p=Object.create(rabbit)
rabbit.__proto__ = animal
let y=new Array(2,3)
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(y))
var val=y.find((b)=>(b==2));
console.log(val);
console.log(Array.isArray(y))
y.__proto__=rabbit
console.log(Array.isArray(y))
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(y))
var ccl=y.find((b)=>(b==2));
```

**Question**: I have created a array and printed its prototype and then called the find method of array and check whether it's an array using `Array.isArray()` method. Then I have assigned the prototype of y to `rabbit object`.

When I checked if it is still an array, I got true, but when calling the find method I get an error and on checking the prototype there was no functions of an array.

Then on what basis does the `Array.isArray()` method returns true.

**Output**:

```
[constructor: ƒ, concat: ƒ, copyWithin: ƒ, fill: ƒ, find: ƒ, …]at: ƒ at()concat: ƒ concat()constructor: ƒ Array()copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()entries: ƒ entries()every: ƒ every()fill: ƒ fill()filter: ƒ filter()find: ƒ find()findIndex: ƒ findIndex()findLast: ƒ findLast()findLastIndex: ƒ findLastIndex()flat: ƒ flat()flatMap: ƒ flatMap()forEach: ƒ forEach()includes: ƒ includes()indexOf: ƒ indexOf()join: ƒ join()keys: ƒ keys()lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()length: 0map: ƒ map()pop: ƒ pop()push: ƒ push()reduce: ƒ reduce()reduceRight: ƒ reduceRight()reverse: ƒ reverse()shift: ƒ shift()slice: ƒ slice()some: ƒ some()sort: ƒ sort()splice: ƒ splice()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()unshift: ƒ unshift()values: ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true, findIndex: true, …}[[Prototype]]: Object
2
true
true
{jumps: true}jumps: true[[Prototype]]: Objecteats: true[[Prototype]]: Objectconstructor: ƒ Object()hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()valueOf: ƒ valueOf()__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()__proto__: (...)get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
Uncaught TypeError: y.find is not a function
    at <anonymous>:17:11
```

Comment: The MDN page for [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) links to ["Determining with absolute accuracy whether or not a JavaScript object is an array"](https://web.mit.edu/jwalden/www/isArray.html).

Comment: Duplicate of [Difference between using Array.isArray and instanceof Array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22289727/1048572). See also [Can I create an object for which Array.isArray() returns true without using the Array constructor or array literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41170131/1048572) and [Can you fake out Array.isArray() with a user-defined object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8672038/1048572) for why your `rabbit` is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on who you ask.

---

The [ECMAScript 2021 Language standard](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-isarray) says:

> 7.2.2 IsArray ( argument )
>
> The abstract operation `IsArray` takes `argument` argument. It performs the following steps when called:
>
> 1. If `Type(argument)` is not `Object`, return `false`.
> 2. If argument is an `Array` exotic object, return `true`.
> 3. If argument is a `Proxy` exotic object, then
>    a. If `argument.[[ProxyHandler]]` is `null`, throw a `TypeError` exception.
>    b. Let `target` be `argument.[[ProxyTarget]]`.
>    c. Return `? IsArray(target)`.
> 4. Return `false`.

(Reformatted for this platform)

It may help to know that built-in Javascript objects have a representation that is internal to the engine. This is what the above pseudo-code is referring to. Javascript doesn't have access to some of the things that the pseudo-code refers to but the engine does.

---

Javascript libraries, on the other hand, typically do one of several things depending on how old the library is, how robust they want to be, or what their goal is. Since they don't have access to the engine internals, these are guesses with a high probability of being correct in the real world:

- Modern libraries defer to `Array.isArray()`
- Polyfills typically use `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Array]'` (standardized by Mozilla, I believe)
- Duck typing: `Boolean(obj) && obj.length != null && typeof obj.push === 'function'`
- Constructor based: `Boolean(obj) && obj.constructor === Array`
- `instanceof` based: `obj instanceof Array`

This is not an exhaustive list.

Comment: So, it basically retains the information in the engine which java script don't have access to??

Comment: @hariharasankar Yes. I believe the two main reasons are: 1) optimizing for the common use case, and 2) conveniently representing a weekly typed language using a strongly typed language.

Answer (score -2):

- `isArray` method takes the argument value and evaluates based on the value.
- When `let y=new Array(2,3)` is executed `y`'s prototype object is `Array` which is having the `find` method, because of which we are able to run the `find` method on `y`.
- But when `y.__proto__ = rabbit` is executed the prototype object of `y` gets changed to `rabbit`, which does not have the `find` method and the value of `y` is still `[2,3]`
- Because of the prototype object change we are loosing the `find` method implementation so we are getting error. `y` value is not changed because of prototype object change because of which `Array.isArray(y)` is returning true.
- You can observe all this by logging `y` value after each step and expanding `[[Prototype]]` object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).